# How to load data from file into linked list c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

The program should read a simple text file and store the data ( name and id) into a linked list.

This is the linked list:

```
struct Prova
{
 char nome[16];
 int id;
};

typedef struct Node {
 struct Prova  struttura;
 struct Node * next;

}TNodo;
typedef TNodo* Nodo;
```

This function creates the linked list:

```
void NewList(struct Prova  p, Nodo * pp)
{
 Nodo  temp;

 temp = (Nodo)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

 temp->struttura = p;
 temp->next = *pp;

 *pp = temp;
}
```

This is the function i wrote to read the file:

```
void Load(Nodo *pp)
{
  FILE *f;
  struct Prova p;
  char * buffer;
  if(!(f = fopen(PATH, "r")))
  {
    perror("Error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Prova));

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f))
    {
      if(sscanf(buffer, "%s%d", p.nome, &p.id) > 0)
      {
        NewList(p, pp);
      }
    }

free(buffer);
fclose(f);

}
```

The text file i'm trying to read is this:

```
Stefano 31
Paperino 23
Pippo 1
Pluto 14
```

The functions for displaying the list are these:

```
void View(struct Prova  p)
{
 printf("%s %d\n", p.nome, p.id);

}

void ViewList(Nodo  nodo)
{
while(nodo != NULL)
{
  View(nodo->struttura);
  nodo = nodo->next;
}
```

The program compiles fine, but it outputs the data in a strange order.
Let me know if you need more info, i think it's all related to the function Load() which is the newest.

Main function is this:

```
int main()
{
int scelta;
 struct Prova test;
Nodo lista = NULL;
 do {
   scelta = Menu();

   switch (scelta)
   {
     case 1:   Load(&lista); break     
     case 2: ViewList(lista); break;
     default: scelta = 0;
   }

 } while (scelta != 0);

 return 0;
}
```

For now the output is this:

[image]

Comment: What did you discover when you ran this code in your debugger? Or have you not tried that yet?

Comment: What's the output order? Note that you're adding elements to the front of your list, so one would expect the output is the reverse of the input.

Comment: `buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Prova));` That might be a bit too small for some  numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because of passing `sizeof(buffer)` to `fgets()`. `buffer` is a pointer and `sizeof(buffer)` will return either `4` or `8` based on underlying architecture `32` bit or `64` bit. Change this to:

```
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(struct Prova), f))
```

as you are allocating `sizeof(struct Prova)` size to `buffer`.

This is also not the correct solution of the problem. Reason is-

Say, your file is having this data:

```
abcdefghijklmno 123456789
```

The name part is `15` character long which `nome` member can hold and `id` member can also hold the number `123456789` as it is less than `INT_MAX`. `fgets` read characters from the stream and the size of above-given data is `25` characters. In your code, you are allocating `sizeof(struct Prova)` size memory to `buffer` and size of `struct Prova` is `20` byte. Hence for the above-given data, `buffer` is not allocated enough memory to read the whole line in one go because the `fgets` reads until `size-1` characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first. So, in this case, the partial line will be read and passed to `sscanf()` and rest of the line will be read in next iteration and passed to `sscanf()` which will give the incorrect results.

You should not allocate the memory to `buffer` based on the size of `struct Prova`. Instead, I would suggest taking `buffer` of some bigger size, like this (no need to allocate it dynamically):

```
char buffer[100];
```

ensure it should be bigger enough to accommodate a line of the file in one read of `fgets` or modify your code to not to fill `p.nome` and `p.id` until `fgets` hits newline character or EOF i.e. to make sure to read the whole line and then only `sscanf()` the `p.nome` and `p.id`.

Comment: @H.S. sorry you're right, comment deleted. But the original code is still somewhat suspect. Anyway there is no need to allocate `buffer` dynamically.